# Replace a character using replaceall in java

Tags: replaceall

Response : "[{"consumerId":"HUL-KUBHIW05D-AJ"}]"

Code written :
String asPrettyString = response.getBody().asString();
String replaceAll = asPrettyString .replaceAll(""", """);

I want to replace " to "

Comment: String replaceAll = asPrettyString .replaceAll("\"", "\"");


want to replace \" to "